# Editing css of elements inside an iframe with javascript

Tags: css

I have an iframe on a page and need to edit the css of elements within it - like color, background images etc. I have the following js, but I am getting the console error "TypeError: doc is undefined". Can anyone help?

```
window.onload = function() {
   let frameElement = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
   let doc = frameElement.contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>.start-screen-search__sub-title:after {content: \' online below, or call: XXX\'; font-size: 22px;}</style>';
}
```

Comment: A comment was deleted for some reason. There are two iframes on the page and the solution is to select one from an array. Someone posted the code but it is now gone, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please use :

```
 let frameElement = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
```

getElementsByTagName returns A NodeList object, representing a collection of elements with the specified tag name. If you want to access an element you have to provide the index.